# Select box arrows aren't showing

Tags: css

I used:

```
`-webkit-apperance:none;
```

on a select box, and now the arrows are not showing. The reason i used this is because the select box styled height would not show in Google chrome on a mac book..

Comment: But that is what `appearance:none;` does — it removes all OS-default styles on your `<select>` element. You will have to use an arrow as a background image... or even better, consider a JS-based replacement.

Comment: Yup, this is by design in Webkit according to [this Firefox ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849). Note Firefox behaves the other way.